# InvalidConstraintException when clearing parent table in C#

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, dataset, relationship, cascade

Maybe I just don't see the forest for the trees, but currently I'm faced with the following situation that puzzles me:

I have a typed data set (not connected to a database), which contains two tables: `Orders` and `Lines`. Each entry in the `Orders` table represents an order and, surprisingly, each entry in the `Lines` table represents one line for an order. There can be multiple lines for each order.

There is a relation between the `Lines` and the `Orders` table connecting them via the order ID. The relation is configured to be a relation as well as a foreign-key constraint, with both the update rule and the delete rule being set to "Cascade".

I'd have expected that clearing the `Orders` table via `set.Orders.Rows.Clear();` would also remove the respective entries from the `Lines` table - however I'm getting an `InvalidConstraintException` saying I can't do that because there are entries in the `Lines` table associated with entries in the `Orders` table.

I can of course work around this by first clearing the `Lines` table before clearing the `Orders` table, but I'm still puzzled as to why the Cascade-rule is not applied in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the `Clear()` shows the error it does with those constraints, but the intended functionality happens when you try to `Remove` a row. With that in mind, an extension method like this does the trick:

```
public static void RemoveAll(this DataTable table)
{
    for (int index = table.Rows.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        table.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
Transactions dataset = new Transactions();
dataset.Orders.AddOrderRow("1");
dataset.Orders.AddOrderRow("2");

dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[0], 1);
dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[0], 2);
dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[0], 3);

dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[1], 1);
dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[1], 2);
dataset.Lines.AddLineRow(dataset.Orders[1], 3);

Console.WriteLine($"Total Number of Lines before delete is {dataset.Lines.Count}"); // Prints 6

//dataset.Orders.Rows.Clear();
dataset.Orders.RemoveAll();

Console.WriteLine($"Total Number of Lines after delete is {dataset.Lines.Count}"); // Prints 0
```

Comment: OK, that's also a nice workaround. I think I'll implement this. Thanks.